# Reading a TSV record into a Perl hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have an array **@fields** containing names for the tab-separated values in **$record** (it may have been populated from record 0 of the file, for instance).

The order of the array entries corresponds to the order of the values in the record.

I want to populate **%hash** with **field => value** entries for each value in the record.

Is there a one-liner to do this?  I can't figure out how to coordinate traversing the **@fields** and **split("\t", $record)** list concurrently.

Best I can come up with is

```
my %hash;
my @values = split("\t", $record);
for my $field (@fields) {
    my $value = shift @values;
    $hash{$field} = $value;
}
```

But I suspect there's a simpler way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is -- it's the [hash slice](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perldata#Slices) notation:

```
@values = split /\t/, $record;
@hash{@fields} = @values;
```

or

```
@hash{@fields} = split /\t/, $record;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
@hash{@fields} = @values;
```

e.g.:

```
my @fields = qw[one two three four];
my @values = (1, 2, 3, 4);

my %hash;
@hash{@fields} = @values;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'three' => 3,
      'one' => 1,
      'two' => 2,
      'four' => 4
    };
```